# Using a library that makes use of the old style "appSettings" in a .Net Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, appsettings

I have a library that makes use of the old style `appSettings` in app.config configuration file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="exampleKey" value="exampleValue" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I realise this is not good practice, but I cannot modify this library and need to use it as is.

In a .Net Core project (I'm trying this in a Unit Test project, but also need it to work in an Asp.Net Web API project), how do I configure an application configuration file so that when the library attempts to load its appsettings (presumably with a `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` command) it loads them correctly? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that is the only thing in that library that is dependent on .NET Framework? I don't know if it is practical for you but you could wrap the library with a web service and call it via RPC instead of in-process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings available in .NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - thanks for the link. Not exactly, I don't think. I have installed the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager NuGet package, but my "web.config" file in my Web Application isn't being used at runtime. Instead a file in my user directory ending "Url_vs0cocxwpbys4l4e3gswszew4ioczhkr\\1.0.0.0\\user.config" is used.

Comment: Ah! I think I have it partially working, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186445/access-web-config-settings-in-asp-net-core-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to piece together the answers to this from other Stack Overflow threads, but just in case anyone comes across this:

In the actual web application, this was solved just by creating an `app.config` file (that sits alongside any `web.config` or `appsettings.json` files you also have) and  setting its Build Action to `Content` and `Copy if newer`. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186445/access-web-config-settings-in-asp-net-core-app) thread.

In the unit test project, this was solved by creating an app.config in the same way as above, but also adding a build action in the csproj file instructing the file to be copied to the output directory and renamed to `testhost.dll.config`. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666780/cant-read-app-config-in-c-sharp-net-core-unit-test-project-with-configurationm) thread.